# How do I retrieve an image url from Cloudinary using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudinary

I uploaded images to cloudinary using `cloudinary.uploader.upload(image, public_id:, function(error, result){console.log(result)})` Cloudinary then gives me the image url of the image that I uploaded.

Is there a way to retrieve an image url from Cloudinary using only my cloud name, api key and the public_id of the image?

Comment: Please go through this documentation. cloudinary.com/documentation/react_integration and here's the repo in GitHub: github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary-react. Feel free to also test out the sample project there

Comment: I am sure you are using some front end for this. If react it will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate the Cloudinary URL directly via Node JS, you can use the cloudinary.url function. It accepts the following:

```
// cloudinary.url("<public_id>.<format>", {<transformations>})  
// Example
cloudinary.url("sample.jpg", {width: 100, height: 150, crop: "fill"})
// Output: "https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_100,h_150,c_fill/sample.jpg"
```

Source: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_manipulation#direct_url_building